# How to arrange the outputs of an array in ascending order using C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

Hi I'm new to programming and currently stuck at trying to get the output of the program to show in **ascending order**,

```
int foo[10];

 for (int i=0; i<=10; i++)

 {

 cout<<"Please enter a number: "<<endl;

 cin foo[];

 }
```

I'm stuck at trying to make it display in ascending order, I tried different methods but to my luck fails me I've seen tons of examples for this question but unfortunately for me I'm only limited to answering this in C++ please can anyone help.

Comment: I suggest you go through a good tutorial on C++. Firstly, your array can only loop from 0 to 9 since it has 10 elements. Also, cin foo[] should be cin foo[i].

Comment: have a look at [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Comment: Unrelated, but your code will not work if you do not change to i<10 so that you prevent an out-of bounds error.

Answer (score 0):

If your assignment allows you to use standard algorithms, then it's simply

```
std::sort(std::begin(foo), std::end(foo));
```

followed by a loop to print them.

If the object of the exercise is to write your own sorting algorithm, then you should [research them yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should run your `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)` instead of `for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)`, because the array has 0-9 indexes, rather than 0-10. Secondly, the syntax for `cin foo[]` is `cin >> foo[i];` in this case.

For the sort, you could look into std::sort, or you could look into some sorts yourself, I would recommend starting with bubble sort, selection sort or insertion sort, as they are the easiest ones to implement.